# Stroke recognition in this kanji?

Tags: kanji, stroke-count

So I'm practicing how to count the strokes of a Kanji. I've been having troubles for this one since I can't find it on Jisho. So I've wanted to ask: am I even right with the number of strokes?

[image: Is the answer right?]

If not, is there an easier way to count the strokes of a Kanji? And since I can't find the Kanji at all, can somebody tell me which Kanji is?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; 12 is correct.

You can look up the stroke count from any dictionary, such as [JDIC](http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1B).

Look at the `[画数]` for `満` and you will see that it is 12.

(At least I think you are looking at `満`)

Comment: Or to provide a resource used by native speakers: http://kakijun.jp/page/12139200.html

Comment: At first I thought it was that kanji, but I was confused because of one particular stroke. After watching the animation, does this mean this stroke is the same? 

http://i.imgur.com/6pwtbAm.png


If so, is it because of how the kanji I used to count the strokes was written in a "Comic" way?

Comment: @TotalNoob Where did you get the original image? Is it from a manga or something?

Comment: I have a friend that helps me either using manga or using a drawing software. I always ask her for help, but she gave me that one. I don't know if she got it from a manga or used a tablet to brush it

Comment: @TotalNoob if you look at the kakijun page, you'll see that the difference doesn't change the stroke count because the standard character make an L shaped stroke where yours just makes a - shape stroke.

Comment: How someone gave me a -1 on this is beyond me; I sometimes wonder why I even bother.

Comment: @Ninj0r I think a user downvoted a lot of posts at random today.  Please don't take it personally.

Answer (score 1):

The (free) computer application [Wakan](http://wakan.manga.cz/) has the option to specify a rough number of strokes and the radical (or radicals) to narrow down your search -- so if you're convinced it has 12 strokes and it's not showing up, expand the window to 11-13 strokes, etc.

This sort of functionality is also available on the (free) [KanjiDraw](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leafdigital.kanji.android) application for Android, and if I recall correctly the Chinese handwriting pad on iOS is one of the few algorithms that is not heavily stroke-dependent (so may recognize your attempt even if you're drawing in 1 stroke something that is properly 2 strokes, which I'm often guilty of)

Comment: +1 For WaKan. This is a great application that I used for many many years. Unfortunately it is old and hasn't been updated since 2008 but it is still a great tool.

Comment: @Ninj0r luckily Japanese has largely stayed the same since then :p (j/k, I catch your drift--it's quite clunky & sometimes outdated, but really overall an excellent tool. my learning improved markedly after installing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following site for the stroke numbers in kanji http://jiten.go-kanken.com/

[image]

[image]

[image]